# iOS check what UIViewContoller is visible from appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, apple-push-notifications

I'm switching between view controllers as followed:

```
ChatWindowViewController *viewController = [[ChatWindowViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

when i receive a push notification i want to know if this view controller is the one on screen now...

I'v tried everything but i seem to be getting it all wrong.

When I try:

```
UIViewController *cont = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];

UIViewController *pVC = self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.visibleViewController;

UIViewController *pVC1 = self.window.rootViewController;

       UIViewController *pVC = self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.topViewController;
```

They all return null.

only this one return something..

```
UIViewController *pVC1 = self.window.rootViewController;
```

but it returns the wrong view controller...

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: are you using a navigation controller ?

Comment: you swap out the root view controller of the window ?

Comment: I set the root view controller when the app loads (in the app delegate) and then don't change it anymore.

Comment: wait, do you display different controllers at different times ?

Comment: you could do self.window.rootViewController.presentingViewController that will tell you if you are presenting a controller, if that is nil then you are not presenting one

Comment: you have 1 view controller as the root and you never swap it out, and you present another controller, and you would like to know which view controller is currently visible, the presented one or the non presented. That is your scenario ?

Comment: I set the root view controller once, and then switch the presented view controller a few times, i want to know what view controller is visible.

self.window.rootViewController.presentingViewController  return null.

Comment: Hmm maybe i have the property wrong, but you say you swap out the presented, so that tactic is irrelevant XD … do you subclass these view controllers that are being presented ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43539/discussion-between---and-asa-dickens)